# Disabling a uibutton in parentview controller after an action performed in its child view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates, protocols, nsnotificationcenter

I have a `viewcontroller`(VC) in which I have created a button programatically. VC is having a series of other subviews. In the subview that comes very last in the hierarchy(CV),i have created a button,on tapping on it I want to disable the button that is added in the parent view controller(VC). I tried following some approaches but on trying to access the button created on parentviewcontroller(VC) from child view(CV) the button on parent view is getting deallocated and it is becoming nil.How can i solve this issue. Please help.(All my views are programatically created).

Comment: Please show the code where you are creating said `UIButton`s and adding the *subViews* and disabling the `UIButton`

Comment: Actually i cannot placed that code as it is a complex classes.So I could explain only the scenario.

Comment: Please provide some code to get to know what is that you have done, so that It would be easy to spot the problem and narrow down the chance of giving long answers.